# What is the reference of this part? Two short rounded bars with a circle between

Tags: part-identification, system

It is similar to a lipstick piece but a bit shorter.
I'm starting to wonder if it's even Lego but if seems pretty compatible
with everything.

[image: two short rounded bars with a circle between]

Comment: If that was in my house, it'd be part of a remote-control or slot-racing car.

Comment: "Compatible with everything" you mean bars/3.18mm, studs, other System or Duplo elements? Which portion of the pictured element is "compatible" shaft ends or its middle? It would be helpful to have another LEGO element placed nearby.

Comment: Actually I retested it and it seems to be a little smaller that the bars. It does not hold as good. It must not be a lego part

Comment: Makes me think of a lego pneumatic piece to connect tubes, but probably isn't... also inclined to think it's not Lego

Comment: Today I discovered part 78258 <https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=78258> which looks very similar, but the ends are longer on the Lego piece.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever brand it is, I don't think it's Mega Bloks, because I got a bulk lot of those recently and found a Mega Bloks piece like this, except its ends aren't rounded like your one (I know my piece is Mega Bloks because it's the same dark speckled grey as the other piece in the photo which says Mega Bloks on it).

[image: Photo of my piece]

[image: Found uses of the piece]

Hope this helps with your search